# unity dictionary value return null

Tags: dictionary, unity-game-engine

i have Dictionary "DebugCommands" in DebugCommandBase

```
    public class DebugCommandBase
{
    private string _id;
    private string _description;
    private string _format;

    public static Dictionary<string, DebugCommandBase> DebugCommands;

    public DebugCommandBase(string id, string description, string format)
    {
        if (DebugCommands == null)
            DebugCommands = new Dictionary<string, DebugCommandBase>();
        string mainKeyword = format.Split(' ')[0];
        DebugCommands[mainKeyword] = this;
    }

    public string Id => _id;
    public string Description => _description;
    public string Format => _format;
}

new DebugCommand("test_command", "test", "test_command", () =>
        {
            //any command
        });
```

In general, everything works well, but when I try to get a value from a dictionary, I get null

```
foreach (DebugCommandBase command in DebugCommandBase.DebugCommands.Values)
        {
            print(command.Description);
            //return null
        }
```

OR

```
print(DebugCommandBase.DebugCommands["test_command"].Format); //return null
```

what is the correct way to get the value from such a dictionary?

Comment: Don’t you normally Add to a dictionary not just decide for it to set a keyword?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you in fact check the command has a populated Description?

Normally, your approach of accessing the values in a dictionary is correct. A similar opportunity to access the values of a dictionary entry is possible by a slight change of code. You'd access each dictionary entry as a keyvaluepair.

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, DebugCommandBase> dEntry in DebugCommamdBase.DebugCommands)
{
    print(dEntry.Value.Description);
}
```

Comment: indeed, the "description" field was not filled... optimize the code and removed a few extra lines in the constructor - and I was looking for the problem deeper than it is